# Button not call post form with Razor C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page with post and wanted when the user clicks on the button "Atualizar", instead of calling the post, called a JQuery. How to do this?

```
<form action="/Conselho/Detalhar/6" method="post">    <div class="row">
        <h3>Visualizando Conselho Profissional</h3><hr>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ConselhoID must be a number." data-val-required="O campo ConselhoID é obrigatório." id="ConselhoID" name="ConselhoID" type="hidden" value="6">
        <div class="col-md-2">           
            <label for="Sigla">Sigla</label> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Sigla" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span><br>    
            <input class="form-control" id="Sigla" name="Sigla" type="text" value="CREA"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">           
            <label for="Descricao">Descrição</label> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Descricao" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span><br>    
            <input class="form-control" id="Descricao" name="Descricao" type="text" value="Conselho Federal de Engenharia e Agronomia"><br>
        </div>                
        <div class="col-md-5">        
            <div class="botoes">   
              <input name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Salvar">&nbsp;&nbsp;   
              <input name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Excluir">&nbsp;&nbsp;   
              <input name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Atualizar">&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Conselho/Index">Voltar</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>          
        </div>        
    </div>    
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to post the form data using an AJAX call? You may not need the form. Or you may just want to intercept the `submit` event instead. What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should add an id attribute so you have an easy, unique selector for the button.  I have given it "Atualizar" in this example
2. Write a javascript event handler for the button
3. Prevent default behavior which in this case is form post.
4. Alternatively, you could use the button tag, and this will not submit the form by default

   var doSomething = function(){
           //your code here
       };
       $('#Atualizar').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           doSomething();
       });

Alternative:
    <button type="button" onClick="doSomething()" id="Atualizar">

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can listen for the click event of this specific button, get the form for this button, serialize the form and post it the action method url.
    $(function(){

```
  $("#Atualizar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit behaviour

    var _this=$(this);
    var _form=_this.closest("form");
    $.post(_form.attr("action"),_form.serialize(),function(res){
      // do something with res
    });

  });

});
```